# spl_object_hash() return different ids

Tags: php, hashcode, spl

I'm learning about [`spl_object_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) and don't quite understand what's behind the scene in this case:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$id1 = spl_object_hash($obj);
$id2 = spl_object_hash(new stdClass);
echo $id1.'<br>'.$id2;
```

Q1. Why `$id1 !== $id2`?

In the reference:

> When an object is destroyed, its hash may be reused for other objects.

Q.2 Is there something relates to that statement? Or I missed something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What does `spl_object_hash` do?

> [Returns a] string that is unique for each currently existing object and is always the same for each object.

To clarify that statement: if you have object A, each time you hash object A, it'll return the same hash value. If you have object A and object B, even if both are of the same type and contain the same values, their hashes will differ, because they're not the same object (instance).

Since you have two different objects, it's expected that their respective ids differ.

Comment: To add re: the quote in Q1 - if you'd destroyed `$id1` before instantiating the second instance of `stdClass` then there's a small chance of the same hash being used again.

Answer (score 2):

Let's examine your code step by step.

```
(1) $obj = new stdClass;
(2) $id1 = spl_object_hash($obj);
(3) $id2 = spl_object_hash(new stdClass);
(4) echo $id1.'<br>'.$id2;
```

1: Create a **new stdClass object**.

2: Get a hash for this object.

3: Get a hash for another **(entirely different) stdClass object**.

4: Echo the ids.

I believe the confusion comes from the third step. You make a new object, completely different from the first one, although it's the same type (class). And the [spl_object_hash](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.spl-object-hash.php) operates on the "object level", meaning it will return a different hash for different objects.